# Send a push notification from a web app to a mobile device to post on Instagram

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm developing a web app that has a scheduling function to schedule posts on Instagram. I need to send a push notification to the mobile device to prompt the post to open in the Instagram app, but we have not developed a native iOS or Android app. Is it still possible to receive the notification in a mobile web browser to then open and post via the Instagram native application? Please advise.

Comment: If the user has the website open on both their mobile device and desktop computer at the same time, then yes, you can communicate between the two (look into AJAX or the WebSocket API). However, the user **must** have their phone and browser on the page at the time - it can't be sleeping and the page can't be in the background. You could look into something like PhoneGap for quickly creating a mobile app from HTML / CSS / JS, though

Comment: Hi Toastrackenigma, thanks for the reply, I appreciate you taking the time to explain the process!

Comment: Any other thoughts from anyone?